# iwlwifi, secureboot and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my X1 Carbon Extreme 2nd. Yesterday I received some software updates and after that my WiFi no longer works with secureboot turned on.

I have learnt that you need to use mokutil to try to sign a key to authorise iwlwifi to run with secure boot enabled, but I can't seem to quite understand how this works.

With secure boot turned on, I get nothing from

```
    sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

```
    sudo modprobe iwlwifi
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': 
Operation not permitted
```

Any help signing the drivers for iwlwifi is much appreciated.

```
    sudo lshw -C network
    
      *-network UNCLAIMED       
           description: Network controller
           product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
           version: 1a
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
```

Update (29.10):
what I did in the end is turn off secure boot - not an ideal solution but got me out of a hole until I need to rebuild my laptop again.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `sudo dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a key to sign your Network Controller.

```
openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf \
        -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 \
        -nodes -days 36500 -outform DER \
        -keyout "MOK.priv" \
        -out "MOK.der"
```

This will create both the public and private keys. This will be useful for signing things for Secure Boot.

Now, cd into the directory where you created the keys, and then do this command;

```
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

Then, it'll prompt you for a password. You could place any password you like, as this'll be extremely useful later on.

Then, reboot your computer. After rebooting your computer, the shim bootloader will execute MOKManager. If you see a Blue Screen with a prompt, you're good. Go to "Enroll MOK", after that, you should follow the menus to sign your keys. Then, you will be prompted for the password that you created for Mokutil. After that, MOKManager will save the keys, and then you should reboot again.

After so, you should be able to modprobe your driver.

Let me know if it helps.